# Oracle convert DECODE to PIVOT or force use of index

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, pivot, decode

I have a very complex SQL view definition that has been inherited and requires altering to improve performance.  It takes a list of records based on a foreign key and displays the rows returned as columns.

Thus :-
Data from select using RANK

```
ID RANK DKEY RECORD1 RECORD2 RECORD3
1  1    1    003     Rob     Emmerry
1  2    2    004     Sue     Emmerry
```

Returns

```
ID REC11 REC12 REC13   REC21 REC22 REC23
1  003   Rob   Emmerry 004   Sue   Emmerry
```

There are 37 columns of data repeated for each returned row upto a max of 5.
Using

```
SELECT ID,
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD1, NULL)) AS REC11
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD2, NULL)) AS REC12
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD3, NULL)) AS REC13
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD4, NULL)) AS REC14
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD5, NULL)) AS REC15
MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD6, NULL)) AS REC16
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD1, NULL)) AS REC21
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD2, NULL)) AS REC22
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD3, NULL)) AS REC23
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD4, NULL)) AS REC24
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD5, NULL)) AS REC25
MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD6, NULL)) AS REC26
FROM 
(
SELECT ID, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dkey) ranking,
RECORD1,
RECORD2,
RECORD3,
RECORD4,
RECORD5,
RECORD6
FROM TABLEA
JOIN
 (SELECT ID, DKEY, RECORD4, RECORD5, RECORD6
  FROM TABLEB
 ) ON TABLEB.DKEY = TABLEA.DKEY AND TABLEB.ID = TABLEA.ID
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

When using the explain plan and filtering on the DKEY field which has an index the index is ignored presumably because of the min/decode statements.

So I thought about rewriting this using PIVOT but don't know how to start.

Any thoughts as to how I can 
a) Get the query to use the index
b) Rewrite using PIVOT

First option is obviously preferable.

Thanks
Craig

**UPDATE**

Here is some sample data showing how my tables are.

```
    Table 1             
    DKEY PID RECORD1 RECORD2 RECORD3
    1    1   3       Rob     Emmerry
    2    1   4       Sue     Emmerry
    3    1   4       Jan     Morris
    4    1   4       Sue     Pye
    5    1   4       Jane    Taylor

    Table 2             
    CID DKEY RECORD10       
    1   3    A      
    2   3    D      
    3   3    G      
    4   3    J      
    5   4    A      
    6   5    A      
    7   5    D      
    8   6    A      
    9   6    D      
    10  6    G      
    11  7    A      
    12  7    D      
    13  7    G      
    14  7    J      
    15  7    M      

    Table 3             
    QID DKEY RECORD3        
    1   3    C      
    2   6    C      
    3   6    F      
    4   7    C      
    5   7    F
```

So tables 2 & 3 link to table 1 with DKEY
If we took the DKEY=3 as an example I would want to see this:-

```
    PID DKEY REC1 REC2 REC3   REC4 REC5 REC6 REC7 REC8 REC9 REC10 REC11 REC12 REC13
    1   3    4    Jan  Morris A    D    G    J    NULL C    NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

There could be up to 5 rows in each of tables 2 & 3.  Fields PID, DKEY, REC1-REC3 from table 1, REC4-REC8 come from table 2 and the rest from table 3.  The other records from table 1 would simply continue on the row so after REC13, DKEY=4 etc etc.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes sorry should have mentioned that, 11g correct.

Comment: On another note that is related to my performance problem.  How do I join DECODE PIVOTS together without reading a view more than once.

Comment: On another note that is related to my performance problem.  How do I join DECODE PIVOTS together without reading a view more than once.  Let me try to explain. I have the above PIVOT which brings together 1 manager say and all his employees up to 5 of them onto 1 row.  Then I have 3 other tables that are keyed against each of those 5 employees and these can also have 5 records each.  The 3 tables are also PIVOTED in the same way as the above table.  How do I join them to the original PIVOT without reading those 3 additional PIVOTS 5 times each?  I'll attach what we are currently doing.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with some sample data from the tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD1, NULL)) AS REC11,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD2, NULL)) AS REC12,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD3, NULL)) AS REC13,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD4, NULL)) AS REC14,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD5, NULL)) AS REC15,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,1,RECORD6, NULL)) AS REC16,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD1, NULL)) AS REC21,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD2, NULL)) AS REC22,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD3, NULL)) AS REC23,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD4, NULL)) AS REC24,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD5, NULL)) AS REC25,
    MIN(DECODE(ranking,2,RECORD6, NULL)) AS REC26
FROM 
(
    SELECT /*+ INDEX(tablea tablea_index) */
        ID,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dkey) ranking,
        RECORD1,
        RECORD2,
        RECORD3,
        RECORD4,
        RECORD5,
        RECORD6
    FROM TABLEA
    JOIN TABLEB
    -- was: ON TABB.DKEY = TABLEA.DKEY AND TABB ON TABB.ID = TABLEA.ID
    ON  TABLEB.DKEY = TABLEA.DKEY
    AND TABLEB.ID   = TABLEA.ID
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks that did force the use of the Index but I forgot to mention that there was also an inner join which I have updated the details.  I was under the impression that the join conditions should cause the index to be used also.  Both joins are against the primary keys and a secondary indexed field.  But I can only get the first table primary index to be utilised.

Comment: That is new: ON TABB.DKEY = TABLEA.DKEY AND **TABB ON** TABB.ID = TABLEA.ID

Comment: Sorry my mistake wrote the join condition incorrectly.  I've tried that and it still doesn't work.  If I simply try the sub select statement with the join both indexes are used.